# Ansible: copy module doesn't keep text formatting

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Task: gather facts from group of hosts with ansible-playbook and put them into a file on a local machine.

My solution:

```
---
- hosts: foo
  order: sorted
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: foo
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: gather foo hosts information
    setup:
    register: gathered_data
  - name: write gathered information into a file
    local_action: copy content="{{ gathered_data }}" dest=/foo/gathered_data.out
...
```

Problem: everything works just fine but output file is one HUGE line. Is it possible to keep text formatting just like `ansible -m setup foo` output?

Also looking for a better solution for this task. Ansible version: 2.4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [filters for formatting data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data), for example:

```
content: "{{ gathered_data | to_nice_json }}”
```

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately "content:" is not working in my case so I have to use "content=" which works just fine.

Comment: Because you use Ansible notation and I included pure YAML. Both notations are equivalent to each other.